# Performing Boundary Select and Sum Attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select-by-location, tools, spatial-query

I´m a MapInfo user, I´ve gone over to QGIS and it´s got a lot going for it, except for some "missing" simple features from MapInfo I just can´t do without.

1. MapInfo Boundary Select - spatial query on the fly to select objects in one layer contained within objects in another layer.
2. MapInfo Sum Attributes - show sum of numerical attribute fields on the fly for selected objected.

QGIS seems to have no simple solution to these.   I've tried to dig out every related plugin I can find, with no real luck.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. Might I suggest (from personal experience) that you'll get better/faster answers by asking each of these three questions one at a time - and perhaps primarily providing a summary of the task rather than by starting from naming the MapInfo tool. Chances are the solutions won't share much in common (i.e. not one plugin). Good luck.

Comment: Splitting these into separate questions with examples of exactly what you're looking for will really help!

Answer (score 3):

I can help with questions 1 and 2 for which I find QGIS solutions quite simple.

**Question 1:** Use the spatial query tool (see doc [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spatial_query.html) and button icon below).

[image]

**Question 2:** Use Vector > Analysis Tools > Basic Statistics (see screenshot below). It is quite intuitive to use: select the vector layer on which you need statistics (like a column sum), then select the attribute on which you need statistics in this layer and validate. The result is a small table with basic statistics on the given layer and attribute.

[image]